# <ion-nav-buttons/> doesn't work with isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to minimize my use of `$scope` as much as possible in an app I'm working on.  In this app, I can't get my nav-bar buttons to work with `ctrl` (using `controllerAs`) unless I don't use an isolated scope.

CodePen: http://codepen.io/rinogo/pen/GjkPdG

As you can see, with an isolated scope (e.g. `scope: {}`), only the buttons that are not in the nav bar work.  However, if we comment out `scope: {}` and inherit the scope prototypally instead, all *four* buttons work.

I can get the "scope method" to work in the nav-bar if I set `test()` on `$scope.$parent` instead.  Given the structure of my app, that's essentially `$rootScope` (aka the scope in which the `<ion-nav-bar/>` is present), right?

It almost seems as if `<ion-nav-buttons/>` is evaluated in the scope of the related `<ion-nav-bar/>` instead of the scope in which it is defined!  Perhaps this also explains why the `ctrl` approach only works with inherited scope, since "behind the scenes" `ctrl` is accessed via the `$scope.ctrl`, right?

So I guess my questions are:

1. Is `<ion-nav-buttons/>` evaluated in the scope of the related `<ion-nav-bar/>`?
2. If so, why?
3. How can I accomplish my goal of calling `ctrl.test()` from `ng-click` in `<ion-nav-buttons/>` (while retaining an isolated scope)?

Thanks in advance for sharing your expertise! :)

Comment: I've discovered that this same issue seems to exist with `<ion-nav-title/>`.

Comment: What am I missing?  Surely someone out there must know what's going on!  Please? :)

Comment: PLEEEEEEEEEEASE

Comment: Pretty please??

Comment: Did you fix it?